# How do I model a single time event in Modelica occurring at a predetermined time?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I want to model a continuous time system which changes its behavior at a certain time instant which is known in advance. A small example is as follows.

```
model time_event
  Real x(start = 0)  "state variable for this example";
  parameter T_ch = 5 "time at which the system dynamics undergoes a change";
equation
  if time <= T_ch then 
    der(x) = x + 1;
  end if;
  if time > T_ch then
    der(x) = -x;
  end if;

end time_event;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is almost fine. Below is your code with a couple modifications.

- Used `if then else` can also do `if then elseif then elseif then ... else`
- Added balance variable `xb` to have common derivative equation (not necessary just a coding style).

Code:

```
model time_event      
    Real x(start = 0)  "state variable for this example";
    parameter Real T_ch = 5 "time at which the system dynamics undergoes a change";
    Real xb "Balance variable for derivative";
equation
    der(x) = xb; 
    if time <= T_ch then 
        xb = x + 1;
    else
        xb = -x;
    end if;
end time_event;
```

Plot of Results:

Red = x

Blue = der(x)

[image: Plot of x and der(x)]

Comment: Thanks very much. Could you please explain what is the reason why the compiler gives an error in my code? As far as I can see, the two codes are the same programmatically.

Comment: An if-equation needs to have the same number of equations in each branch. Here because it needs to know in which equation der(x) is solved. You had 2 different equations for der(x), which should give an error. This answer just moved the intermediate xb out of the equation which is not necessary unless you want to plot that variable. Note that if your condition only involved parameters (not time), the compiler might have been able to evaluate the branches; in those cases the if-equation does not need to be balanced since some of them will be removed.